# test_should_destroy_product(ProductsControllerTest) issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I have the following:

```
def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

and my test:

```
test "should destroy product" do
    assert_difference('Product.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, :id => @product
    end

    assert_redirected_to products_path
  end
```

and I get:

```
# Running tests:

...............F......

Finished tests in 0.628844s, 34.9848 tests/s, 55.6577 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_should_destroy_product(ProductsControllerTest) [/Users/noahc/Dropbox/Projects/depot/test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:51]:
"Product.count" didn't change by -1.
<2> expected but was
<3>.

22 tests, 35 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/usr/l...]>
```

Any ideas why this is failing?

**Update**

If I comment out:

`before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item`

```
#ensure that there are no line items referencing this product
    def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
      if line_items.any?
        return true
      else errors.add(:base, 'Line Items present')
        return false
      end
    end
```

The test passes. BUT, @product has no line items. It is just a fixture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add [`to_param`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) in the `@product`:

```
test "should destroy product" do
assert_difference('Product.count', -1) do
  delete :destroy, :id => @product.to_param
end

assert_redirected_to products_path
end
```

Comment: I already tried that, and it didn't fix it. But you got me thinking about the params, being passed and I'm able to get it to work by commenting out a line (see update above). I tried it with and without to_param and it worked both ways.

Comment: I don't know if I really understand your method, but if there are no line items `if line_items.any?` returns [false](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F), right? So, it goes to `else` and generates the error... 'Line Items present'

Comment: Yeah, I needed to change `.any?` to `.empty?`.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this as you probably don't want to comment out that callback preventing a product from being deleted if it's still in someone's order history (for future purchases or current purchases, I would implement an active/inactive status column that would be evaluated before final checkout; still allows product viewing, but prevents checkout, in the case of the product being out of stock for example). These tests take the before_destroy in product.rb into consideration. Here I'm simulating on-the-fly what it would look like if a product was never purchased. Alternatively, you could try updating your fixtures.

```
test "product has line items" do
  assert_not_equal 0, @product.line_items.count
end

test "product has no line items" do
  @product.line_items.each do |item|
    item.destroy
  end

  assert_equal 0, @product.line_items.count
end

test "should destroy product" do
    assert_difference('Product.count', -1) do

    # "simulate" a product that has never been added to cart
    # alternatively you could update your fixtures to do this

    @product.line_items.each do |item|
      item.destroy
    end

    delete :destroy, id: @product
  end

  assert_redirected_to products_path
end
```

Finally, be sure to update your controller and view to add this flash notice so you can see what's going on:

```
# DELETE /products/1
# DELETE /products/1.json
def destroy
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  if @product.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "#{@product.title} successfully deleted"
  else
    flash[:notice] = "It appears there are other carts that currently have #{@product.title} so we won't delete it at this time"
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to products_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

In your view for your products where the Destroy link will be, ensure you have the notice being printed at the top if you decide to use this:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```